# how to make django work on debian 11? – python error: KeyError: 'django'

Tags: python-3.x, django, debian-based, mailman

a few monthes ago, i installed mailman3 on clean installed debian 10 vm, with success – the server was working for long time and distributed hundreds of mails without any issues. The [tutorial i implemented completely is that one announced by GNU Mailman itself](https://wiki.list.org/DOC/Howto_Install_Mailman3_On_Debian10).

After [regular debian system upgrade process](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade) from 10 to 11 (didn't ever added external package sources, so it was really easy) i tried starting mailman 3 again. Everything works, **except the django web framework** – that one controlled by [qcluster.service](https://wiki.list.org/DOC/Mailman%203%20installation%20experience?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=systemd_qcluster.txt).

The problem seems to be within executing `/opt/mailman/mm/bin/django-admin migrate`; the output is as follows (`journalctl -u qcluster.service` contains the same lines):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyperkitty/templatetags/decorate.py", line 4, in <module>
    from hyperkitty.lib.renderer import markdown_renderer, text_renderer
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyperkitty/lib/renderer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from mistune.scanner import escape_html, escape_url
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape_html' from 'mistune.scanner' (/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mistune/scanner.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/bin/django-admin", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'hyperkitty.templatetags.decorate': cannot import name 'escape_html' from 'mistune.scanner' (/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mistune/scanner.py)
```

output of `pip freeze | grep django` (be it that it helps):

```
django-allauth==0.47.0
django-appconf==1.0.5
django-compressor==3.1
django-extensions==3.1.5
django-gravatar2==1.4.4
django-haystack==3.1.1
django-mailman3==1.3.7
django-picklefield==3.0.1
django-q==1.3.9
djangorestframework==3.13.1
```

I already made sure that there aren't any unsolved pip package dependencies, but that doesn't seems to be the problem...
I already tried to recreate python env, tried different python versions (Python 3.7.12, 3.8.12, 3.9.2 and 3.9.9) but that all didn't work either, googled half the web (found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51845964/17852350) but nothing helped :-(

Comment: Is Django installed? Can't see it in your pip list.

Answer (score 1):

Mistune has moved several functions from scanner to util, see [this commit](https://github.com/lepture/mistune/commit/46a65a978b005651dcc54a340e44aef71f9f7e95#diff-66d139461fe6262eb4c0b1919274c06a8a43c3271e66bf26ce2df3be633561e1).

So you have to change `from mistune.scanner import escape_html, escape_url` to `from mistune.util import escape_html, escape_url` in `/opt/mailman/mm/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyperkitty/lib/renderer.py` as the error message suggests.

PS: Use `pip freeze | grep -i django`, because it appears as `Django`.

PS2: Seems like other mailman3 users are as unhappy as you are about the mistune dependency, see their [gitlab bugtracker](https://gitlab.com/mailman/hyperkitty/-/issues/395). This also means that hyperkitty devs should be aware of the new stable mistune version (they had a dependency on the 2.0 release candidate after which the refactoring in question happened).